# Bit compression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, encoding, compression

Is there a way to compress a JavaScript array of 250+ 1s and 0s into something a little more manageable (say a shorter string) and then manageably decompress the same? Sort of like the way Google did its image encodings...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give you almost 1:5 compression by encoding as base 32. I chose to include a simple length value to make it allow variable-length. Please see [this fiddle demonstrating the technique](http://jsfiddle.net/y2rma/) with two functions that allow you to round-trip the value. (Or you can see an earlier, more naive [hexadecimal version](http://jsfiddle.net/EcSpe/) I created before @slebetman reminded me of the native number base conversion that exists in javascript.)

Here's sample output for one set of 250 1s and 0s. The number of characters does not count the leading "250|":

```
base 32, 50 chars: 250|qgl6alf1q2lbl1aclau3k5ana2kpals78alek59ilboeglajgu
base 16, 63 chars: 250|D42A6555E1D0AABA854CAABC3A155750A995578742AAEA1532AAF0E85553878
```

You can use a base 64 encoding to get it down to 42 characters, but be aware that with both the base 32 and base 64 versions you can end up with words in your final result that may be objectionable (please see the fiddle above for an example). The hex version can also have objectionable content, but much less so (a bad face bade a dad be a cad?)

Please let me know if you need to save 8 more characters and I will work up additional script for you. Avoiding vowels could be one way to deal with the objectionable word problem. Let me know if you need to do this as well.

If your bit strings will *always* be 250 characters, then the functions can be simplified a bit, but I didn't want to make this assumption.

For reference here's the bits-to-base-32 function.

```
function bitstringEncode(bitstring) {
    var i, l = bitstring.length,
        retval = l.toString() + '|';
    for (i = 0; i < l; i += 5) {
        retval += parseInt((bitstring.substr(i, 5) + '0000').substr(0, 5), 2).toString(32);
    }
    return retval;
}
```

This function will pad to the nearest 5 bits, and may generate a spurious extra character at the end for the length you are providing. I included a second version of each conversion function that pads to the nearest 10 bits, which may generate up to two spurious extra characters. I included them because if speed is important, they *may* (or may not) be faster, as they take larger chunks from the inputs.

Comment: Is it in an array or in a string? `[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]` or `'11000011'`?

Comment: It can be either - I can do array.join("") and vice versa.

Comment: I'm writing code... what form is it in now? And is it in the browser or on the server side? Do you need a round trip back to bits or just one way?

Comment: I do need a round trip. Essentially I'm saving a sequence of notes (on or off) that are 250 notes long, so I want to save that sequence, compress it, and eventually decompress it.

Comment: It is on the browser now (JavaScript).

Comment: @Rio Use `a.join("")` as payload of a *POST* request.

Comment: I need to be able share the URL (with the pattern encoded), so saving to the DB is not my main concern.

Comment: @Rio As an alternative to base64, you could transfer the notes as sequences of large hexadecimal numbers where precision is sufficient: `parseInt(a.slice(…).join(""), 2).toString(16)`. The greater the base, the shorter the string. You can go up to base 36 this way without an extra library.

Comment: Yes, @PointedEars, I'm working on a base 32 version. Using base 36 would be very difficult as it doesn't align easily with binary.

Comment: Using base 32 is easy because you can do `toString(32)`. Base 64 is harder because then you have to construct your own characters for the value.

Comment: It would be appropriate to add a note as to from where you got your ideas for updates.

Comment: [`String.prototype.substr()` is proprietary](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.2). Use [`String.prototype.substring()`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4). Better yet, [`Array.prototype.slice()`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4) AISB.

Comment: @PointedEars I will be happy to add a note that slebetman reminded me of the native base conversion that exists in javascript. Which browser does `substr` not work in?

Comment: You are asking the wrong question because [*there is no javascript*](http://PointedEars.de/es-matrix). You should ask "In which *ECMAScript implementation* does it not work?" and the correct answer (per my research) is that it did not work as specified in the non-normative Annex B of ES 5.1 before JScript 9.0.16440. That would be before IE 9.0 and friends. But that is beside the point. It is a *non-standard* method, so you should not rely on it and should not use it in new code. Especially not when the standards-compliant and well-supported `String.prototype.substring()` exists.

Comment: @Rio Which version are you going with? If you want base 16, you're best off tweaking the base 32 version by changing 4s and 5s to 3s and 4s, and 32 to 16.

Comment: This could be much more efficient if you encoded more bits per step, used 36 as base, and maybe a delimiter. The only thing that stands in the way is IEEE-754 precision, so the slice to be encoded cannot be arbitrarily long.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19662/discussion-between-erike-and-pointedears)

Comment: Please do see the chat. Base 36 will save ONE character on the 250-bit string.

Answer (score 2):

(There has not been much explanation in the other answers, so in addition to presenting my approach, I would like to discuss the approaches presented so far in my answer. Please bear with me.)

As other answers indicate, an array of bits can be treated as a stream of bits, which is essentially a rather large number written in base 2.  The same number can be written in another number base.  Because single characters other than decimal digits can be used for higher value digits in greater number bases (such as "F" or "f" for 15 in hexadecimal), the greater the number base, the fewer digits (characters) are required to display it.

As suggested in those answers, you can use base64 encoding and even greater bases (the Unicode Base Multilingual Plane has 65536 code points, and [conforming ECMAScript implementations support that](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-2), so base 65536 is a distinct possibility although [you would have to percent-encode much again for URIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1)), but in ECMAScript that would require a user-defined function, perhaps a library containing it; at least it requires a non-native implementation of the conversion algorithm which is necessarily slower than a native one.

Fortunately, ECMAScript implementations have built-in methods that allow you to convert numbers from one base to another, from base 2 to 36 inclusive.  There is [`parseInt(string, radix)`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) with which you can convert a numeric `String` value `string` written in base `radix` to a value of the `Number` type, and there is [`number.toString(radix)`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.2) with which you can convert the `Number` value `number` into a numeric `String` written in base `radix`.

However, because [the ECMAScript `Number` type is an implementation of IEEE-754 double-precision floating-point numbers](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19), there are *several* limits to integer precision.  AIUI one is that, for a bit array full of ones, unless your array does not contain more than 53 bit-elements (or your string does not contain more than 53 "1"s), you cannot convert the entire bit string forth and back without loss of precision.  ([The significand of IEEE-754 doubles has a precision of 53 bits.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64))

But you can view a large (binary) number as a concatenation of smaller (binary) number strings, split up the original bit stream in small enough chunks and convert each chunk to the greater base.  In any case, information on consecutive high bits that are `0` is lost for each chunk.  So when restoring the bit stream from the conversion result, you need to pad each chunk on the left with zeros so that each decoded chunk is as long as the original chunk.  The chunk size needs to be weighed against the number of steps it takes to encode the stream and the number of zeros that need to be padded when decoding it.

AIUI, if you process the bit stream from left to right, the number encoded by each chunk will potentially be greater, therefore the encoded string will be potentially longer, even with a greater base, because high bits in chunks might be set (for example, compare the right-bound `11|001|001` – 3|1|1 – with the left-bound `110|010|01` – `6|2|1` –, both have chunk size 3).  The reason for encoding your data in the first place was a *short* URI.  So as the stream is finished before encoding, you should process the stream from right to left instead.  (This approach also removes the necessity of including in the encoded string the number of original bits if that number is a multiple of the chunk size.)

These considerations lead to the following *general* (for readability, not fully optimized) functions:

```
/*
 * @param bitArray : Array[Number|String]
 * @param chunkSize : optional Number = 53
 * @param chunkBase: optional Number = 36
 * @param delim : optional String = ","
 *   Delimiter to use.
 * @return string
 */
function bitEncode (bitArray, chunkSize, chunkBase, delim)
{
  var chunkArray = [];
  if (!chunkSize || chunkSize < 2 || chunkSize > 53)
  {
    chunkSize = 53;
  }

  if (!chunkBase)
  {
    chunkBase = 36;
  }

  for (var i = bitArray.length; i > 0; i -= chunkSize)
  {
    var index = i - chunkSize;
    if (index < 0)
    {
      index = 0;
    }

    var slice = bitArray.slice(index, i);
    var chunk = parseInt(slice.join(""), 2).toString(chunkBase);
    chunkArray.unshift(chunk);
  }

  return chunkArray.join(delim);
}

/*
 * @param input : String
 * @param length : Number > 1
 *   Target length of input after left-padded with zeros
 * @return string
 */
function leadingZero (input, length)
{
  input = String(input);

  var inputLength = input.length;
  if (inputLength >= length)
  {
    return input;
  }

  var padding = [];
  padding.length = length + 1 - inputLength;

  return padding.join("0") + input;
}

/*
 * @param s : String
 * @param chunkSize : optional Number = 53
 * @param chunkBase : optional Number = 36
 * @param delim : optional String = ","
 * @return Array[string]
 */
function bitDecode (s, chunkSize, chunkBase, delim)
{
  var chunkArray = s.split(delim || ",");
  var bitArray = [];
  if (!chunkSize || chunkSize > 53)
  {
    chunkSize = 53;
  }

  if (!chunkBase)
  {
    chunkBase = 36;
  }

  for (var i = 0, len = chunkArray.length; i < len; ++i)
  {
    bitArray = bitArray.concat(
      leadingZero(
        parseInt(chunkArray[i], chunkBase).toString(2),
        chunkSize)
      .split(""));
  }

  return bitArray;
}
```

As you can see, the default chunk size here is 53 bits, and the default base is 36.  Thus, an array of 250 random bits –

```
var a = [];
for (var i = 250; i--;)
{
  a[i] = +(Math.random() < 0.5);
}
```

– which could be (in right-bound chunks of 53 bits)

```
/*
              "11111110110011110011000011001010101010\
11010011111010010010100110100100010011001011001010111\
00100100010000101110011010000011100010010101011100011\
11100010110110111001101110000100011101101111101111100\
10001110110100010101110010011100110110100101110010011"
*/
a.join("")
```

would be encoded by default as

```
/* "3hou1lt6,21ewvahkfvb,ck8t6olnmr,26lbvliu2rg,1dh74lghy8j" (55 characters) */
var s = bitEncode(a)
```

and can be decoded like so:

```
var a = bitDecode(s);
```

These *general* functions should allow you to vary the chunk size and base so as to optimize the encoded string for your use-case.  (Any potentially offensive words might have been split in two because of the delimiter.)

However, note that the decoded array will contain extra leading zeros if the original array length is not a multiple of the chunk size.  If that possibility exists, and poses a problem, you can fix that problem by passing along the original length, as suggested by ErikE, and then using that value:

```
var originalLength = …;

a = a.slice(a.length - originalLength);
```

or (in all major implementations except JavaScript before version 1.6 and Opera ECMAScript before version 9.52)

```
a = a.slice(-originalLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just crafted this very naive implementation.

It will convert between `"111000111"` and `[['1',3],['0',3], ['1',3]]` (and vice-versa).

Hopefully, it should work well with large binary strings, which should have a lot of repeating characters. In the worst case (`01010101...`), you will use `1+7*n` characters (`n` being the size of the input string).

Hopefully, someone will have a more efficient solution ?

```
var compress = function (input){
    var output = [], current = null;
    for (var t = 0; t < input.length; ++t ) {
        if (current === null || current[0] !== input[t]) {
            current = [input[t], 0];
            output.push(current);
        }

        ++ current[1];
    }

    return output;
};

var decompress = function (input) {
    var output = '';

    for (var t = 0; t < input.length; ++t) {
        for (var u = 0; u < input[t][1]; ++u) {
            output += input[t][0];
        }
    }

    return output;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation that converts the 1s and 0s to hexadecimal. On the server it should be fairly simple to convert it back to 1s and 0s. Converting to hex basically stores 4 bits per character so it will convert your sequence of 250 bits to 63 characters.

Be warned though, this converts data in 4 bit chunks so you'll need to pad your sequence to either 252 bits (for 4 bit alignment) or 256 bits (for 8 bit alignment). The implementation below does not handle the padding since I don't know from which end you would want to pad the data:

```
function binArray2HexArray (binArray) {
    var hexArray = [];
    while (binArray.length) {
        hexArray.push(parseInt(binArray.splice(0,4),2).toString(16));
    }
    return hexArray;
}
```

Obviously you can then join the returned array to convert it to a hex string.

If you pad your data to 8 bit alignment you can speed up the function a bit by operating on 8 bits per loop by changing the splice parameters to:

```
binArray.splice(0,8)
```

Similarly, if you pad your data to 16 bit alignment you can speed it up again by splicing 16 bits at a time. The limit I believe is 32 bits before javascript starts rounding numbers due to floating point representation. I'd be more comfortable with 16 as maximum since I'm not sure how the various javascript engines would treat signedness of 32 bit integers.

Comment: I like it! Let me give it a whirl

Comment: I get strings of 1s and 0s in my hex?

Comment: I also tried http://freebeer.smithii.com/www/_source.php?file=%2Fhome%2Fross%2Fpublic_html%2Ffreebeer%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fbin2hex.js and it converted 1000000000000000011111000000010000000100100110000100000000100000000000100010100100000000000000000000000001000000000000000010000000000001000000001000100000000000000000000000010000000000000100000000000000000000

Comment: into 
31303030303030303030303030303030303131313131303030303030303130303030303030313030313030313130303030313030303030303030313030303030303030303030313030303130313030313030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303031303030303030303030303030303030303130303030303030303030303031303030303030303031303030313030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303130303030303030303030303030313030303030303030303030303030303030303030

Comment: Oh sheesh good job, I forgot that parseInt takes a radix parameter! Scrambling to fix crazy mistake... lol :)

Comment: P.S. Note that this is destructive to the input array.

Comment: @Rio: That freebeer code is different. It's trying to convert each ASCII character into hex. So it's output 31,30 is actually the conversion of the characters "1" and "0". It makes sense that the freebeer code doubles the size of your string since by definition it takes two hex characters to encode a single ASCII character.

Comment: If you want to preserve the original array you can always use slice instead of splice and keep track of the index while looping.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use base64? I wrote something like this a while ago, but it uses typed arrays:

https://github.com/beatgammit/base64-js/blob/master/lib/b64.js

Basically just turn your 1s and 0s into bytes and base64 encode it. Base64 can be passed in a URL, so it would work for your situation.

Comment: Given that there are POST requests and gzip Transfer-Encoding, base64 is overkill here.

Comment: @PointedEars - The OP didn't give a lot of detail into what he needs it for. If it needs to be part of a GET query param, then perhaps base64 could make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Arh ! I have finally found an article that I have read few months ago. It describes multiple ways to compress efficiently a string, you should give it a try : [this is it](http://www.bitsnbites.eu/?p=20).

Technics mentioned in the paper :

- base64
- latin1
- utf-16
- png

Answer (score 0):

Both these functions expect a string input:

```
// input size must be less then 256 characters
// first byte in returned output is length of original string
// this is used during decoding for correct padding of last 8 bits
function encodeBits(input) {
    var output = String.fromCharCode(input.length);
    while(1) {
        output += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(input.substr(0,8),2));
        input = input.substr(8);
        if(input.length == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return output;
}

function decodeBits(input) {
    var output = "";    
    var bits;
    var finalLength = input.charCodeAt(0);
    input = input.substr(1);

    while(1) {
        bits = input.charCodeAt(0).toString(2);

        // string must be left padded with 0's
        while(bits.length < 8) {
            if((bits.length+output.length) == finalLength) {
                break;
            }
            bits = "0"+bits;
        }

        output += bits;

        input = input.substr(1);
        if(input.length == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

**Encoding**

```
var instr = "101001110010100110010000111011111010110110001001111010110110";
var encStr = encodeBits(instr);
```

You can encode your output using *escape*

```
var escapedStr = escape(encStr); // returns '%3C%A7%29%90%EF%AD%89%EB%06'
```

**Decoding**

Decode using *unescape*

```
var unescapedStr = unescape("%3C%A7%29%90%EF%AD%89%EB%06");
var bitStr = decodeBits(unescaped);

// bitStr now contains original input
"101001110010100110010000111011111010110110001001111010110110"
```

As an alternative to escape/unescape you could also use [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.btoa) and [atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.atob) which will give you shorter encoding.

These functions and their usage are demonstrated in this working example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/EU4nL/

Comment: `escape()` and `unescape()` are not always Unicode-safe. Use `encodeURIComponent()` and `decodeURIComponent()` instead. `btoa()` and `atob()` and non-standard and (even per the referenced documentation) not suited for Unicode characters.