# Convert a large amount of base36 text to base 2 text

Tags: javascript

I have large amounts of binary values that I want to (more) compactly store as strings, so I was using binary -> base36 conversion by using

`parseInt('0101010101010 etc', 2).toString(36)`

However, when attempting to reverse this calculation with

`parseInt('base36 value', 36).toString(2)`

there is a loss of accuracy as everything after some number of digits gets cut off, I would assume because of floating point limitations.

What is the correct/better way to accomplish this?

Ex: My base 36 is `dkmgiancyx44so4ck8gwgkoc8gk4ks8ks48kook0co8w04sk4scokkgk800kk4w08s4s0oso0g8w0g8kkggskosw48s00wgo04wgw0g4okg04kg0okswc8ogg4s4skkscccg44o8so084ckocosoo4sokkgco8gg4ggocscg08goo4c0cw0kcscso` 
but running parseInt(text,36).toString(2) yields
`10000010100101100000000000000000001100011000001101111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Comment: Try chunking it maybe?

Comment: by chunking, do you mean calculating the base2 string in chunks and then appending it together?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. Split the base36 string into chunks, convert each chunk, and then append the result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bit compression in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408485/bit-compression-in-javascript)